# using awk to remove specific white space and replace with semicolon

Tags: awk

I am new to linux and the command line. I am trying to find a command to that will allow me to replace `white space` (in a .csv text file) with a semi-colon **for all fields except the first**. Please see example below, any help would be gratefully received, I have spent a long time looking for a solution. If you do have an answer could you please explain the command so I can try and learn how and why. Many thanks.

Example of input text:

```
0   k__Bacteria  p__Firmicutes   c__Bacilli             
1   k__Bacteria  p__Firmicutes   c__Clostridia      
2   k__Bacteria  p__Bacteroidetes    c__Bacteroidia     
3   k__Bacteria  p__Bacteroidetes    c__Bacteroidia
```

What I need the out put to be:

```
0   k__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes;c__Bacilli        
1   k__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes;c__Clostridia    
2   k__Bacteria;p__Bacteroidetes;c__Bacteroidia   
3   k__Bacteria;p__Bacteroidetes;c__Bacteroidia
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat file
0   k__Bacteria  p__Firmicutes   c__Bacilli     foo     bar
1   k__Bacteria  p__Firmicutes   c__Clostridia  the   quick     brown
2   k__Bacteria  p__Bacteroidetes    c__Bacteroidia     fox jumped      over
3   k__Bacteria  p__Bacteroidetes    c__Bacteroidia     the lazy dogs back

$ awk -v skip=1 '{match($0,"([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){"skip"}"); head=substr($0,1,RSTART+RLENGTH); tail=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1); gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,";",tail); print head tail}' file
0   k__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes;c__Bacilli;foo;bar
1   k__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes;c__Clostridia;the;quick;brown
2   k__Bacteria;p__Bacteroidetes;c__Bacteroidia;fox;jumped;over
3   k__Bacteria;p__Bacteroidetes;c__Bacteroidia;the;lazy;dogs;back

$ awk -v skip=2 '{match($0,"([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){"skip"}"); head=substr($0,1,RSTART+RLENGTH); tail=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1); gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,";",tail); print head tail}' file
0   k__Bacteria  p__Firmicutes;c__Bacilli;foo;bar
1   k__Bacteria  p__Firmicutes;c__Clostridia;the;quick;brown
2   k__Bacteria  p__Bacteroidetes;c__Bacteroidia;fox;jumped;over
3   k__Bacteria  p__Bacteroidetes;c__Bacteroidia;the;lazy;dogs;back

$ awk -v skip=3 '{match($0,"([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){"skip"}"); head=substr($0,1,RSTART+RLENGTH); tail=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1); gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,";",tail); print head tail}' file
0   k__Bacteria  p__Firmicutes   c__Bacilli;foo;bar
1   k__Bacteria  p__Firmicutes   c__Clostridia;the;quick;brown
2   k__Bacteria  p__Bacteroidetes    c__Bacteroidia;fox;jumped;over
3   k__Bacteria  p__Bacteroidetes    c__Bacteroidia;the;lazy;dogs;back
```

Comment: Hi Ed, many thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for me. Could this be due to the input file being a csv file? or maybe that some of the white space is tabs not just normal spaces (i think the white space between fields is maybe a tab and single space in my file)?

Comment: No and no. The most likely problem is that you created your file on Windows and so it's got spurious control-Ms in it. Try running dos2unix on it then rerun my script. If that doesn't work then maybe you're using old, broken awk - what does awk --version tell you?

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your time. The file was created in Ubuntu, which was only installed a couple of weeks ago. I am new to linux so am still learning! In regards to the awk version i get "awk: not an option: --version", what does this mean? Your command was run from my home/user directory. Thanks again.

Comment: copy/paste the sample file I posted and run my command on it and see if that works. If it does then the problem is your input file. If it doesn't then the problem is your awk. Since your awk doesn't support --version it's functionality is already questionable so I'd recommend you download and install GNU awk from http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/ anyway.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, installed gawk 4.0.1 (via ubuntu software centre in the end as had problems with manual installation) and now your command works perfectly. Thank you for you time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in python like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for line in sys.stdin:
        cols = line.split()
        print ' '.join([cols[0], ';'.join(cols[1:])])
```

Just `chmod +x script` the file and execute it `./script < input`.

Note that line.split() will split by multiple whitespaces, that is `'a    b\tc'` will yield in `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Being a newbie to the world of linux I am not confident enough to play with python. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution is `awk`. it can be dirty and someone can refine that but it works

`awk 'OFS=";"{a=$1;$1="";$0=a";"$0}sub(/;;/," ",$0) ' temp.txt`

Output is

```
0 k_Bacteria;p_Firmicutes;c_Bacilli
1 k_Bacteria;p_Firmicutes;c_Clostridia
2 k_Bacteria;p_Bacteroidetes;c_Bacteroidia
3 k_Bacteria;p_Bacteroidetes;c_Bacteroidia
```

---

```
cat temp.txt
0 k_Bacteria p_Firmicutes c_Bacilli
1 k_Bacteria p_Firmicutes c_Clostridia
2 k_Bacteria p_Bacteroidetes c_Bacteroidia
3 k_Bacteria p_Bacteroidetes c_Bacteroidia
```

**EDIT: Update** as per comments

Try this awk script `myawk.sh`

```
 BEGIN { print "Begin Processing "}
   OFS=";"{
       $9=$9"%%"
   b = $0;
   split($0,a,"%%");
   gsub(/;/," ",a[1])
   print a[1]a[2]
   }
  END {print "Process Complete"}
```

Execute with `awk -f myawk.sh temp.txt` where $9 is the variable uptill which u want to keep spaces

Comment: One quick question, say I have more than the 4 fields listed above (actually have 17) and wanted to keep more than the first field as described above (i.e. waned to keep the first 9 fields with just a space and the remaining fields joined with a semicolon) could I alter your awk command to do this? If so how? Many thanks again.

Comment: Works a treat!! Thank you so much for your time and help. Just saved me hours/days of going in circles!!

Comment: Actually i am also new to awk , spent 2 hours , to solve your problem. Just trying to learn more. Experienced person should have done it in seconds

Comment: Do OFS assignment in the BEGIN section, not in the condition part of the body. You don't use "b". If you want to use this approach (I wouldn't as it mangles white space and relies on %% not being present in the input but YMMV), get rid of the OFS assignment completely and change your gsub() to `gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,";",a[2])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v OFS=";" '{$1=$1" "$2;$2="";gsub(/;;/,";",$0);print}' your_file
```

or may be in perl:

```
perl -F -lane 'print join ";",@F' your_file| perl -pe 's/;/ /'
```